# What SWT classes are used in the Android ADT AndroidManifest.xml screen?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'd like to write an Eclipse plugin that looks like the "AndroidManifest.xml" editor page in Google's Eclipse ADT plugin - specifically, [this screen](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/2873/androidmanifestscreen.png). I'm new to SWT development, though, so I don't have a very good understanding of what SWT components one would use to build a screen like this.

So, specifically, I'm asking:

- Is there a particular layout I should use to build a screen like this?
- What class gives the collapsible headers, like "Application Attributes", with the color-gradient backgrounds?
- Are there any source-code examples available for a screen like this?
- Better yet, is the source code of the ADT plugin available anywhere? I haven't found it online.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this part of your question:

> Better yet, is the source code of the
>   ADT plugin available anywhere? I
>   haven't found it online.

The ADT source is public. See http://tools.android.com/ for more info. Specifically, [this page](http://tools.android.com/build) describes how to get and build the source. You should be able to find what you are looking for somewhere in the source tree.

Comment: Thank you, this was enough for me to find answers to my other questions in the ADT source.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted Marc's answer, but I wanted to give a more detailed answer here, for the benefit of anyone who comes along later:

- The form in question is an example of a "Managed Form". I should have read this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html
- For the layout, org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData and org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ColumnLayout seem to be common choices.
- The collapsible headers are a feature of the org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section class.
- Javadoc for the Eclipse Plugin Development Kit, including the classes named here, can be found at http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/overview-summary.html